# Using class member not state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make class member `file_name`

I don't want to use `this.state` because I don't want to render when `file_name` is changed.

```
class ListMix extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.file_name = "";// it shows the error.　
                        //TypeError: Cannot set property 'file_name' of undefined
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result :[]
    }
  }
  render(){
     return();
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you just need to call the `super(props);` before calling `this.file_name = `

Comment: wow,,, thank you  my careless mistake.

Comment: added as an answer :) Quick question though, why do you want a property exactly, if it's not bound to the state of the component? To me, it looks a bit like a misuse of a React component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple one, you just need to call `super(props)` before adding the `file_name` property :)

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.file_name = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*The basic/simple understanding of OOPS concept.*

When you extend a class with another, and if you use constructor, then you have to use super function to inherit the extended component's properties first. **The rule is inherit the properties from the extended component then build your main component**. Otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it is nice help to understand the reason.